# Understanding nested function reference in parfor loop

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I came accross this sentence in MATLAB doc:
The body of a parfor-loop cannot make reference to a nested function. However, it can call a nested function by means of a function handle.

Can someone please explain what this means?

Comment: This may help: [nested functions](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) and [function handles](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html)

Comment: I understand what terms nested function and function handle mean. How do you explain in this context? What limits is parfor loop imposing?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used `parfor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `parfor` loop is different from a normal loop, in that the body of the loop has its independent workspace for every iteration. In fact, when you are running the `parfor` loop on a parallel pool, the variables that need to be transmitted to the loop body are saved and reloaded (that's, by the way, the reason for the "variable x cannot be sliced which may lead to communication overhead" warning: Having to save and reload huge variables may add quite a bit to your processing time).

Consequently, calls to nested functions won't work - the nested function in the parent function no longer shares its workspace with the loop body. Furthermore, nested function calls may alter workspace variables across iterations of a loop, which won't mesh with parallel execution.

In contrast, passing a function handle, or calling a separate function, works fine. The function defined in the function handle, as well as the separate function, have their own workspaces, nothing gets shared across iterations of the `parfor` body, and thus the iterations can run completely independently.

/aside: Creating a function handle to a nested function may still be able to cause you problems: a live function (as opposed to a function handle stored as string which you "activate" with `str2func`) handle can carry quite a bit of the existing workspace, including handle objects. Both the size of the workspace and the not-being-passed-by-reference (because of save&reload) may lead to unhappiness.